# Highcharts tooltip for single series always centre. Can I force it to be left hover of the marker?

Tags: highcharts

highcharts example it has two series:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ]
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
});
```

1 - hover over the series and the tooltip is always appears on the left (unless at the border of the viewport)
2 - Click on one of the legend item to hide 1 line.
3 - hover over the single line.  I noticed that the tooltip is always centre to the marker.

How can I always make the tooltip hover to the left of the marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tooltip.positioner` callback to achieve the desired effect.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9of37Lyx/

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    positioner(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
      return {x: point.plotX - labelWidth / 2, y: point.plotY}
    }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

Comment: Thanks for the example!